# Best way to delete millions of rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a Table with 1 trillion rows and 8 Indexes, 2 Foreign keys and is partitioned by a column which hold year. For each person I calculate the year (separate package) and less than that year data should be deleted. Currently the last partition has 651 millions rows and I need to delete around 6 million rows from this partition. Below are the things i have tried

1. Vanilla delete - took lot of time
2. Bulk FORALL and DELETE - took lot of time
3. Exchanging Partition - this is the fastest but all the 8 indexes go to unusable state and i need to rebuild all of them which takes time again. Currently the Exchange partition is also not working as the parent table has hidden columns and partition throws error saying

   > ORA-12996: cannot drop system-generated virtual column

This table has 300 000 people and I calculated the year for each person and now looping through each person and deleting them but committing after deleting each individual.

Comment: What would be the rough amount of records to keep? You could consider copying those, truncating the table and re-inserting.

Comment: out of 650 million in a partition I want to delete about 500 million. Tried to use CTAS and then reinsert but again it takes time as table has 8 indexes.

Comment: Definitely do not commit after deleting each row.

Comment: @DavidAldridge if i don't do that the undo retention table is being filled and exception is thrown. I commit after deleting per individual.

Comment: It's guaranteed to make the deletion as slow as it possibly could be. the fix for hat problem is either to use an operation without so much undo, or to increase the undo space available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

1. Creating a new non-partitioned table
2. Create indexes on it
3. Use direct path (APPEND) nologging insert to add the rows you want to keep.
4. Perform partition exchange
5. Truncate non-partitioned table
6. Repeat from (3) for other partitions
7. Drop non-partitioned table
8. Take backup

Note that the indexes are built during the insert, by logging the required data into temporary segments that are then scanned to build the indexes, rather than full scanning the table itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
create table tablewithrelevantdata unrecoverable as select * from tabletobedeleted where ....;
drop table tabletobedeleted;
rename tablewithrelevantdata to tabletobedeleted;
create index tabletobedeleted_idx1 on tabletobedeleted(c1,c2) unrecoverable parallel 5;
```

Since you have indexes, I will double check if there are indexes on composite tables like

1. Student
2. Teacher
3. Class

Here `Class` is having id of student and teacher as primary key. Index on `StudentId` and `Teacherid` in `Class` is important.

Also, you can use delete like:

```
SET TRANSACTION USE ROLLBACK SEGMENT <test_segment>;
DELETE FROM tabletobedeleted WHERE <some_condition>
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I can use a CTAS and copy of the data i want to keep but it has 2 problems. First the table has 1 trillion rows and i want to delete only 600 millions rows.Secondly it has 8 indexes and creating them or rebuilding them takes time. Will try the set transaction delete though

Comment: CTAS is not appropriate in your case (I still mentioned). you can also try deleting in batches.

Comment: else you can simply copy the rows which are needed into a new table, delete the old table, rename the new table as old table and then have a rollback segment. (This is similar to CTAS)